# Can AMP pages use a redirecting URL in the canonical tag?

Tags: google-search, search-engines, amp

I recently changed the URLs of my articles and they are now 301 redirected to the new URL format. However, the AMP equivalent version of those articles **rel="canonical"** tag still links to the old version of the URL (now a 301 page).

Is this ok?

Ie, given `<link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL">` , can `$SOME_URL` be a redirected page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [official documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery/?format=websites), they only refer to a `200 OK` absolute URL, so, in this case, and to be completely sure there is no problem with a `301 redirect` URL, I'll use the [URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en) (Google Search Console) to verify Google can access to the final URL.

[image]

You can also use **test live URL** option if you did some changes to the URL and want to check them right ahead. If everything is correct you should see 0 error in your GSC AMP's report.

[image]